# Access XML data via javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, nodes, getelementsbytagname

How can I get the value of my xml data using a javascript. Im accessing my xml file on my domain, and view it on the client side.

my.xml

```
<usr>
  <uid trk="1234">
    <getThis>kdzbnya</getThis>
  </uid>
</usr>
```

I want to get the value of "getThis"

sample.js

```
function alertThis(){
        var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        var xmlFile = "my.xml";
        xmlDoc.async="false";
        xmlDoc.load(xmlFile);
        xmlObj=xmlDoc.documentElement;
        try {
            var v = "";
            $.each(xmlObj.childNodes, function(i, valThis) { 
                if(valThis.getAttribute("trk") == "1234"){
                    v += valThis.getElementsByTagName('getThis').nodeValue;
                }   
            });
             alert(v);
        }
        catch(e){
            alert(e);
        }
}
```

but it returns undefined value.

Comment: you know this wont work in Firefox, right?

Comment: @DmitryB yes, the activexObject you mean, but I'm only working this on IE because it's for the windows 7 gadget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using jQuery.

change

```
v += valThis.getElementsByTagName('getThis').nodeValue
```

to

```
v += $(valThis).find('getThis').text()
```

Comment: Yeah thanks! It works. Yes, I have to use jquery because I have to many data to get.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a `.item(0)` or `[0]` between `getElementsByTagName(...)` and `.nodeValue`:

```
v += valThis.getElementsByTagName('getThis').item(0).nodeValue;
```

You'll need this as [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList) (which can resemble an `Array`). The list won't have a [`nodeValue` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeValue) itself, but the nodes within it should.

Comment: It returns null, maybe because there's some problem on my jquery code.

Answer (score 1):

See this example http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp of an XML parser. 
But in reality you probably want to use a framework to load the XML and parse it. There is plenty of them out there, check microjs.com for the features that you are looking for.