# Call SOAP Service using jQuery and ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, web-services, soap

I have to call a Webservice with a user name, password and a key I got from a provider.

The login to the service works fine an I get a result. The result is attached.

In this result is a key wich I have to use for my next requests.

How can I read out the result an store the Value in a variable to use this for my next steps?

Thank you all very much ahead!!

Hear is the code wich give me the Result:

```
$("#btnCallWebService").click(function (event) {
            var wsUrl = "http://myServerURL";

            var soapRequest =
                '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
                <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" \
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" \
                    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
                  <soap:Body> \
                    <WMLogin xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> \
                      <sUserName>' + username + '</sUserName> \
                      <sPassword>' + password + '</sPassword> \
                      <sAppKey>' + appKey + '</sAppKey> \
                    </WMLogin> \
                  </soap:Body> \
                </soap:Envelope>';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: wsUrl,
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: soapRequest,
                success: processSuccess,
                error: processError,
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",

            });

        });


function processSuccess(data, status, req) {
        if (status == "success") {
            $("#response").text($(req.responseXML).find("WMLoginResult").text());

        }
    }


    function processError(data, status, req) {

        if (status == "error")
        alert(req.responseText + "  " + status);
    }
```

The response i get after my request is:

```
<OutputData>
   <ReturnValues>
      <Name>LoginKey</Name>
      <Value>eefe058a7da44675a25cd16bc9a83c90</Value>
      <RecordID>-1</RecordID>
   </ReturnValues>
   <ReturnValues>
      <Name>UserMenuXmlString</Name>
      <Value />
      <RecordID>-1</RecordID>
   </ReturnValues>
   <Data>
      <ID>22590</ID>
      <Username>username</Username>
      <Passwort>password</Passwort>
      <Name>Name</Name>
      <Vorname />
      <...>
      <...>
      <...>
   </Data>
   <WebServices>
      <Anwendung>Anwendung1</Anwendung>
      <ProgrammPfad>https://myServerAddress/app1</ProgrammPfad>
      <WBM_WebMethodName>WMGetAFT_Auftrag</WBM_WebMethodName>
   </WebServices>
   <WebServices>
      <Anwendung>Anwendung2</Anwendung>
      <ProgrammPfad>https://myServerAddress/app2</ProgrammPfad>
      <WBM_WebMethodName>WMGetAUA_Auftragsart</WBM_WebMethodName>
   </WebServices>
   <WebServices>
      <Anwendung>Anwendung3</Anwendung>
      <ProgrammPfad>https://myServerAddress/app3</ProgrammPfad>
      <WBM_WebMethodName>WMUpdateAFT_Auftrag</WBM_WebMethodName>
   </WebServices>
</OutputData>
```

I need to store the value inside the tag . 
I this example  I need "eefe058a7da44675a25cd16bc9a83c90" inside the tag

```
<Value>eefe058a7da44675a25cd16bc9a83c90</Value>
```

Thank yo very much again!

//----------------------My Answer here-------------------->

First of all....thank you all guy for you answers!!!!

@tmarwen:

thank you for this!

I tried to use your code and replaced my function as follow with console logging commands:

```
function processSuccess(data, status, req) {
      if (status == "success") {
        var xmlDoc = req.responseXML // Your XML document entry
        var xmlObj = xmlDoc.documentElement;
        console.log ( 'processSuccess started' ); //executet
        try {
            console.log ( 'processSuccess --> try started' ); //executet too
          $.each(xmlObj.childNodes, function(key, val) {
              console.log ( 'processSuccess --> try --> each started' ); //executet too
            if ($(val).find("Name").text() == "LoginKey")      //I don not get true
            {
                console.log ( 'processSuccess --> try --> each if "LoginKey" found true' ); //not reached
              alert($(val).find("Value").text());

            }
            else {
                console.log ( 'Did not find "LoginKey"' ); //this will be executed
            }
          });
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log ( 'catch started' );  //not executed
        }
      }
    }
```

...but i did not get the needed result.

The logs in the console tells me:

```
[Log] processSuccess started (Login+Auftrag_stackoverflow.html, line 110)
[Log] processSuccess --> try started (Login+Auftrag_stackoverflow.html, line 112)
[Log] processSuccess --> try --> each started (Login+Auftrag_stackoverflow.html, line 114)
[Log] Did not find "LoginKey" (Login+Auftrag_stackoverflow.html, line 122)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844385/access-xml-data-via-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can retrieve data from an XML response and store it in a tag -

http://www.think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/

You just have to do changes in your function processSuccess().

Comment: sorry but this link does not work for me...i don't get any answer from the server

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to retrieve the `Value` of the *LoginKey* matching element:

```
function processSuccess(data, status, req) {
  if (status == "success") {
    var xmlDoc = req.responseXML // Your XML document entry
    var xmlObj = xmlDoc.documentElement;
    try {
      $.each(xmlObj.childNodes, function(key, val) {
        if ($(valThis).is("ReturnValues") && ($(val).find("Name").text() == "LoginKey"))
        {
          alert($(val).find("Value").text());
        }
      });
    }
    catch(e){
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work. The result I got is in my firs message, because I do not have enough reputation points.

Comment: The error seems a bit weird and I can't get right to the cause. But i might be because of elemnts not having `Name` element, so you would add a statement to check the current element type (whether a *ReturnValues* or not). I updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I got it since Wednesday evening!

Today I am not in the office.

On monday I will share the solution with you.

Thank you all. You helped me very much to get it!

Here is the result wich is working for me:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: wsUrl,
                    contentType: "text/xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: soapRequest,
                    success: processSuccess,
                    error: processError,
                    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    complete: function() {
                        $(responseData).find("ReturnValues").each(function() {
                            $("#output").append($(this).find("Value").text());
                            keyValue = $(this).find("Value").text();
                            console.log(keyValue);
                        });
                    }
                });
```